# React-router- change url on data fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working with `React Router` and I want to change url after data has been fetched. I was trying many solutions but any of them seem to work. One of the solutions was `this.props.history.push('/some/path')` but wherever I put it I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I use `import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You might not be getting history in your props:**

You need to make use of the `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

then you need to export your component with `withRouter`:

```
export default withRouter(componentName)
```

then you can use the line:

```
this.props.history.push('/some/path')
```